# Media analysis java library

Tags: java, groovy, media, analysis

As a "learn Groovy" project, I'm developing a site to manage my media collection (MP3, MP4, AVI, OGG) and I wasn't able to find any open source library to retrieve meta data from this files. I was thinking of something like Linux's file command.
I've found few libraries on Java that do one or the other (like mp3info), but not a total solution even for just music files.
Does such a library exists? Will this become another hobby project?
Thanks for the answers

Comment: I forgot to mention, JMF is not an option since I don't find a way to make it work under Linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [Entagged](http://entagged.sourceforge.net/) Library for getting metadata from media files

Comment: Very interesting. Seems like they are already doing what I want to achieve except for the movie files. Thanks. I'll keep this question open for a few more days anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to exec an external process, [ExifTool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) can extract metadata from just about every file format ever invented. Dispite the name, it can pull metadata from more than just jpgs with exif tags.

Comment: There are many tools that I know of that can achieve this... but not in Java

Answer (score 0):

As a last resort, you could use a dump from mplayer:

```
mplayer -identify -frames 0 filename
```

Comment: That's the sort of thing I would prefer to avoid.